# Chrome and Firefox displaying block instead of inline

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I have a bunch of links with an image in front. I can't use a list because the image is different for different links. It looks like I want it to in IE, but for some reason Chrome and Firefox put a line break between the image and the link. (line breaks added for clarity)

```
<img src='/Images/newsicon.png'  
 style='width:12px;
        height:12px; 
        border:0px none white; 
        visibility:visible; 
        display:inline;
        padding: 0px;'
 title='Read Article' alt='Read Article' /> <a href='Link'>Text</a>
```

When I use the inspect element in chrome I'm getting this as the list of styles for the element:

```
width: 12px; 
height: 12px; 
border-top-width: 0px; 
border-right-width: 0px; 
border-bottom-width: 0px; 
border-left-width: 0px; 
border-top-style: none; 
border-right-style: none; 
border-bottom-style: none; 
border-left-style: none; 
border-top-color: white; 
border-right-color: white; 
border-bottom-color: white; 
border-left-color: white; 
padding-top: 0px; 
padding-right: 0px; 
padding-bottom: 0px; 
padding-left: 0px; 
visibility: visible; 
display: block; 
opacity: 1;
```

I'm assuming this might be happening in FF too. No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, so we have a jQuery applet called PrettyPhoto that is apparently setting the Display to block. Don't know why it is not doing it to IE... When I disabled the PrettyPhoto script import it displayed it correctly. Now I have to dig through it to figure out how to make it ignore some images, or at least not change inline to block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have separate stylesheets for IE vs other browsers? What it sounds like to me is there's a more important style overriding the display: inline.

Comment: Yeah. There was a jQuery script that was preloading the images and fading them in. I hate it, but our graphic designer is adamant about keeping it... I went in and removed the `, display:'block'` part from `images = $('img', this).css({opacity:0, visibility:'visible', display:'block'}),` and now it looks good again...

Answer (score 0):

img must be display: block to function correctly which is why the browser is most likely overriding it. To get the desired effect use:

```
display: inline-block;
```